# maven plugin error after importing project to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, riak

I've imported a [Basho Riak Java library](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client) as an eclipse project after git cloning it, using the `Existing Maven Projects` import dialog option of eclipse. I have done that in order to explore this library using eclipse's `Open Declaration` feature, in order to better use this library.

I am getting this error in the Problems pane:

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.3.201306030806:prepare-agent (execution: jacoco-initialize, phase: initialize)

Can you explain in layman terms that assume little to no Maven knowledge, what does it mean, and what may be a path towards a solution for this case? I have scant knowledge of maven, I typically use Scala's sbt for my Scala projects, and looking for a practical gentle in-context introduction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem linked to the Maven Eclipse plugin (m2e).

I might be fixed, but for this we need to know the version of the plugin you are using.

You can find some info here for instance : 
https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

You can search in google for "plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration m2e" for more information.

But if you don't want to bother, this error should not prevent you to use the eclipse features to navigate through the project.